# only Tag edits in questiosn

Tags: discussion, editing, tags

can any mod send message to this user

if he wants to add tag edits only he can do after 2K reputation

https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/202465

Comment: A bit lite to the discussion, but are tag-edits a problem for <2k users? Is there a policy that says they are?

Comment: its okay if some one is doing 1-2 tag edits a day its okay , if more then that please wait unless you have 2k reputation.